# import "packageName" in React returns babel error

Tags: reactjs, import, jestjs, babeljs

I am trying to implement a markdown text editor with format buttons.

I've found a library which provides me the tools to implement these buttons: https://github.com/github/markdown-toolbar-element
In their documentation, they import like library like this:

```
import '@github/markdown-toolbar-element'
```

Everything is working fine, but in the end, tests are failing because of this kind of importing.

```
 Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/mnt/c/Users/BogdanBledea/Desktop/Projects/project/node_modules/@github/markdown-toolbar-element/dist/index.js:580
export default MarkdownToolbarElement;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

> 22 | import '@github/markdown-toolbar-element'
```

Comment: The instructions in the error message are pretty clear. What are you still curious about?

Comment: I've done everything that was stated in the info, but the error was the same